# How to consume a Tailwind component from another node project?

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I have 2 services in my project: "**front-user**" which contains everything in my app and "**front-admin**" which contains reusable components. I was using emotion with MUI and decided to switch to Tailwindcss in both services.

#### Versions

I'm using react-scripts v5.0.1 which, according to the documentation, doesn't require ejecting CRA's configuration.
I'm using tailwindcss v3.3.2 in both front-user and front-library.

### Tailwind config files

Here is my tailwind.config.js from front-user:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    presets: [require('../front-library/tailwind.config')],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

It uses front-library's preset configuration :

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: {
                    100: '#def3ea',
                    200: '#a5dac3',
                    400: '#1DB479',
                    600: '#199C69',
                },
                danger: {
                    400: '#ee8686',
                    600: '#ea6868',
                },
                neutral: {
                    0: '#fff',
                    100: '#fcfcfc',
                    300: '#d4d4d8',
                    400: '#9897a8',
                    1000: '#000',
                },
            },
            fontWeight: {
                normal: '400',
                semibold: '500',
                bold: '700',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

The goal here is to have 1 source of truth, which is the configuration from front-library.

### CSS files

My front-library/src/main.css and front-user/src/index.css files both contain the strict minimum (Tailwind directives) :

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

### The issue

In front-user I can use Tailwind class utilities:

```js
export const Test: FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <p className="pl-5 my-5 text-danger-400">Test</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

This works fine and it uses the variables from front-library's configuration file.
In front-library I can use Tailwind within my storybook and it works fine as well.

**However**, when I try to export this Button component :

```
export const Button2: FC<ButtonProps> = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            className="flex justify-center items-center gap-2 py-2 px-4 rounded-md"
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

from front-library and use it in front-user, it renders [this atrocity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OefmQ.png)

### What I tried

I tried to create a [PostCSS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwWFO.png) in front-user and use TW configuration file from front-user and front-library, with no success.

I can see all TW utility classes in the Test component in the Devtools, but for some reason Tailwind can't associate these utilities with the ones in front-library config file.

Here is how front-user and front-library are linked:

```json
"scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm explore front-library -- npm install && npm explore front-library -- npm run build",
        "prestart": "npm explore front-library -- npm run build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have a nice week-end !

Comment: You can achieve this using two ways:
1. Webpack [ModuleFederation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation)
2. Using monorepo(s) with [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [Nx](https://nx.dev/recipes/adopting-nx/migration-cra)